# Applet is not running in java6 and it is working using java7

Tags: java, applet, java-7, java-6

I am using applet code in my application. When I am running that applet it is aksing me to install java 7 version.

**Is it mandatory to install java7 version?**
**If it is mandatory how the applets were run in java6 version previously?**

I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it mandatory to install java7 version.

Basically, yes.  And you should do it anyway, since Java 6 is no longer getting security patches.

> If it is mandatory how the applets were run in java6 version previously.

The author has (presumably) changed something.  He/she might have started using Java 7 language constructs or Java 7 specific library APIs.  Or he/she might have just changed the JNLP configurations to force you to upgrade **for your own good**.

Comment: If i use only java6 related code then java6 is enough to run my applet.

Comment: @PSR - provided that it was compiled with Java 6 (or earlier) as the target, then yes ... technically.  But it is a bad idea to not upgrade.